# AWK: Trouble with AWK (print between two patterns) not working as expected

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I've tried searching but have not found the answer I'm looking for.  For this scenario, I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONN="mysql://username:password1@hostname/database_name"

echo "Connection:\t${CONN}"

PW=$(echo ${CONN} |awk '/username:/,/@/')
echo "Username:\t${PW}"
```

I'm trying to set the new variable of PW to the value of password1.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need awk here. Just BASH is good enough:

```
conn="mysql://username:password1@hostname/database_name"
[[ "$conn" =~ username:(.*)@ ]] && pw="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "$pw"
password1
```

Comment: Wow, that is perfect.  Looks like I have some more reading to do on bash.  I knew bash was powerful, but that is downright cool.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: But keep in mind that it works only for bash 3 or above (no '=~' in posterior version) the solution that i proposed work on all bash versions :)

Comment: @Ko2r: `BASH 3` was released in 2004 about 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Just do that :

```
 TMP="${CONN##*:}"                       //Delete all characters from the head till the last ':'
 CONN="${TMP%%@*}"                       //Delete all characters from the tail till the last '@'
```

and you have password1 in CON

Answer (score 0):

Personally (so probably not the best choice), I would use `cut` for this:

```
PW=$(echo -e ${CONN} | cut -d":" -f3 | cut -d"@" -f1)
```

Running it yields:

```
Connection:    mysql://username:password1@hostname/database_name
Username:      password1
```

NOTE: If you're going to use `\` in `echo` make sure you use the `-e` option

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are trying to use:

```
awk '/username:/,/@/'
```

will find the LINES between a LINE containing `username` and a LINE containing `@`. It is not intended to find a string between delimiters within a line. Try:

```
sed 's/.*username:\(.*\)@.*/\1/'
```

instead. It's not robust but it may be all you need for your specific input.

IMHO you should use @Ko2r's solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Another Bash:

```
CONN="mysql://username:password1@hostname/database_name"
IFS=:@ read UN PW __ <<< "${CONN#*//}"
echo "$UN" ## Outputs username
echo "$PW" ## Outputs password1
```

Compatibility: Bash 2.05b or newer